# What is the probability that the sum of a subset of the remainders a number m excluding 0 of gives you a multiple of m?

Tags: probability, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was wondering: given an integer $m$, we get its set of remainders $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, m-2, m-1 \}$. Now, if we exclude $0$, we get the integers from $1$ to $m-1$, which is the subset I'm interested in. If we select a  subset of these integers, **what is the probability the the sum of the members of that subset gives you a multiple of $m$?**

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume every subset has the same probability to be chosen? In this case $1/2^{m-1}$

Comment: More likely something close to $1/m$.

Comment: This has a strong smell of local central limit theorem :-)

Comment: Yes, every subset has the same probability to be chosen. Also, the maximum sum is when you sum all the non-zero remainders of m, which gives you $\frac{(m-1)m}{2}$, which is a multiple of $m$, but there's only one subset that produces this situation, whereas for multiples of m around $\frac{1}{2)\frac{(m-1)m}{2}$, there are much more subsets that sum up to the same result, so...

Comment: I'll add here some equivalences. If we calculate the number of possible subsets that give us a multiple of m we can find that sequence in OEIS ( https://oeis.org/A063776 ). There is a good formula there, which I assume originates in this paper ( https://web.archive.org/web/20150912170614/https://math.berkeley.edu/~lpachter/papers/modpaper2.pdf ) that lets us prove that your probability is exactly $1/m \sum_d 2^{1/d} \phi(d)$ where the sum is on $d|m$ and $d$ odd. I don't know how to continue but I let this here in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computing the first few values and searching OEIS yields [OEIS sequence A000016](https://oeis.org/A000016) (the lowest OEIS index I’ve ever encountered, I believe). The entry provides the formula

$$
a_m=\frac1{2m}\sum_{d\mid m\atop 2\not\mid d}\phi(d)2^{m/d}\;.
$$

As pointed out by ACheca, a proof is given in [An interesting result about subset sums](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/493b/c8edac22bde43775d44359c855828f96e3db.pdf?_ga=2.124571599.434720309.1582308102-535812486.1574099598) by Nitu Kitchloo and Lior Pachter. (The result there is twice ours, since $m$ is included, so each of our admissible subsets yields two, one with $m$ and one without.) The corresponding probability is

$$
p_m=2^{-(m-1)}a_m=\frac{2^{-m}}m\sum_{d\mid m\atop 2\not\mid d}\phi(d)2^{m/d}\;.
$$

I doubt that this can be further simplified. For $m$ an odd prime, this is

$$
p_m=\frac1m+\left(1-\frac1m\right)2^{-(m-1)}\;,
$$

which is close to $\frac1m$ as expected.